# How to run apache-superset in background when installed in windows using miniconda3 (Anaconda Prompt)

Tags: windows, anaconda, miniconda, apache-superset

I was able to install apache-superset in windows using miniconda3 and able to run superset application using the anaconda prompt and console level output image is attached.

**Command used :** python "{path-to-superset.exe}\superset.exe" run -p 8088 --with-threads --reload --debugger

can anyone help me out in running apache-superset at service level in windows.
i.e., In simple terms, if I close the anaconda prompt(miniconda3) the application should be running fine at a windows service level or running in background is also appreciated

[image: Running at console level]

Answer (score 0):

you can try docker...

simple steps:

- install docker for windows
- download the code
- launch superset with 'docker-compose -f docker-compose-non-dev.yml up'

Useful Links

- https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/installing-superset-using-docker-compose/
- [Install apache superset on windows 10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RnPhYxWwVgc)